# What is the SsoLoginContrib extension setting for AuthTokenName when using Keycloak as IDP?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, twiki

I'm using Twiki and the SsoLoginContrib extension with Keycloak to set up SSO. The LocalSite.cfg settings require $TWiki::cfg{SsoLoginContrib}{AuthTokenName} but I don't know what that setting should be when using Keycloak. How do I find the AuthTokenName in Keycloak?

I've tried 'AUTH_SESSION_ID', 'KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY' and 'KEYCLOAK_SESSION' because they were set in the cookie after successful authentication with a  Keycloak user.

$TWiki::cfg{SsoLoginContrib}{AuthTokenName} = 'KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY';

I would expect the authentication to succeed and redirect to the Twiki/bin/view/Main page but there is no redirect, only the Keycloak realms//account page for the authenticated user.

Comment: please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reach out for help and use the resources available but I get "please format your question properly." 
I used the 'wizard' provided by stackoverflow and entered the information.
I searched the web using multiple search engines.
I really had hoped the community was mature and friendly enough to help but my expectations are obviously too high. 
The times have changed, the internet is now full of arrogant brats that have grudges against the world because they were bullied for being nerds. I understand that.
I give up.